# MSSQL Collation on Update Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, collation

We have an MSSQL Server with a linked server that contains a few views. We are trying to update a field from a table on the main server with values from the views from the linked server.

When we execute the query we get this error regarding collation:

```
Mens. 468, Nivel 16, Estado 9, Línea 6
No se puede resolver el conflicto de intercalación entre "Modern_Spanish_100_CI_AS" y "Modern_Spanish_CI_AS" de la operación equal to.
```

One example of the update we need to do:

```
Update therefore.dbo.thecat10

Set alias = (SELECT therefore.dbo.vClientes.alias
                        From therefore.dbo.vClientes
                        Where therefore.dbo.thecat10.codigo=therefore.dbo.vClientes.código)
WHERE therefore.dbo.thecat10.codigo = ( SELECT therefore.dbo.vClientes.código
                               FROM therefore.dbo.vClientes
                               Where therefore.dbo.thecat10.codigo = therefore.dbo.vClientes.código)
```

I tried adding collate Modern_Spanish_CI_AS after the comparrison but it is not working.

Comment: What are the collations of `therefore.dbo.thecat10.alias` and `therefore.dbo.vClientes.alias`? Also, I can't see COLLATE in that query? What was the query you tried with COLLATE?

Comment: I added COLLATE after the Where clause, but no change. The server's collation is Modern_Spanish_CI_AS and the linked server is Modern_Spanish_100_CI_AS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Update cat set
  alias = cli.alias
FROM therefore.dbo.thecat10 cat
INNER JOIN therefore.dbo.vClientes cli
  on cli.código COLLATE Modern_Spanish_CI_AS = cat.codigo
WHERE cat.alias != cli.alias COLLATE Modern_Spanish_CI_AS
```

Comment: I just ran the query and while it gives me no errors, it doesnt update the field. 0 rows affected.

Comment: Well, I can't see your data. Try to adapt `where` conditions to your situation. Anyway, the collation issue is fixed now, right?

Comment: I removed the last Where clause. I dont think it was needed, tho i am not an expert. It seems the fields were updated i Will check the integrity.